# Java, sorting ArrayList using comparator

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I want to sort my list of `Task` object by two criterion. First it is sorted by `leftEntryTime` and then by `timeNeededToBeProcessed`.

Can someone help me?

So far I did sorting by `leftEntryTime` but how I can sort it by `timeNeededToBeProcessed` in the same `Comparator` class?

```
 Task(int procesID, int neededTime, int waitingTime, int leftEntryTime) {
    this.procesID = procesID;
    this.timeNeededToBeProcessed = neededTime;
    this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
    this.leftEntryTime = leftEntryTime;
 }
```

This is my `Comparator`:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TimeEntryComparator implements Comparator<Task> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
        int entryTime;
        int taskTime = o1.getLeftEntryTime()- o2.getLeftEntryTime();

        if (taskTime > 0){
            return 1;
        }

        if (taskTime < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

then I sort it by:

```
Collections.sort(list, new TimeEntryComparator());
```

Comment: add one more if? what is the issue? are you getting unexpected results? please share them

Comment: let me shorten your code: `public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) { return (o1.getLeftEntryTime() - o2.getLeftEntryTime()); }`

Comment: What is the unit of time stored in `leftEntryTime` and `timeNeededToBeProcessed` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to do:

```
@Override
public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
    if (o1.getLeftEntryTime() == o2.getLeftEntryTime()) {
        return o1.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed - o2.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed();
    } else {
        return o1.getLeftEntryTime() - o2.getLeftEntryTime();
    }
}
```

This will compare the `Task` objects by `LeftEntryTime` and if the `leftEntryTime` properties are equal, it will compare their `timeNeededToBeProcessed` properties.

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
public class TimeEntryComparator implements Comparator<Task> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
        if (o1.getLeftEntryTime() == o2.getLeftEntryTime())
            return o1.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed() - o2.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed();
        return o1.getLeftEntryTime() - o2.getLeftEntryTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using some new Java 8 functionality, it's actually pretty easy and elegant:

```
Comparator<Task> byLeftEntryTime = (t1, t2) -> Integer.compare(t1.getLeftEntryTime(), t2.getLeftEntryTime());
Comparator<Task> byTimeNeededToBeProcessed = (t1, t2) -> Integer.compare(t1.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed(), t2.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed());

list.sort(byLeftEntryTime.thenComparing(byTimeNeededToBeProcessed));
```

Answer (score 0):

When the comparison of the leftEntryTime values gives 0 (i.e. they are equal), then continue to compare by timeNeededToBeProcessed, e.g.:

```
@Override
public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
    int compare = o1.getLeftEntryTime()- o2.getLeftEntryTime();
    if(compare != 0) {
        return compare;
    }

    return o1.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed() - o2.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that you want to sort your `Task` objects by a compound key consisting of their `leftEntryTime` and `timeNeededToBeProcessed` fields.  A `Comparator` that represents such an ordering would look like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TimeEntryComparator implements Comparator<Task> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
        int entryTime;
        int taskTime = o1.getLeftEntryTime()- o2.getLeftEntryTime();

        if (taskTime > 0){
            return 1;
        } else if (taskTime < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            int neededTime = o1.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed()
                    - o2.getTimeNeededToBeProcessed();

            if (neededTime > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if (neededTime < 0) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```